# Why I am getting HTTP 404 Not Found for getting access token using Mircrosft Graph API

Tags: python, sharepoint, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get access token using microsoft graph api via postman. I have provided client id and client secret (please refer to the attached screenshot). I am getting http 404 not found error. I am using following endpoint for fetching access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image: API request parameters]

[image: Api response]

I trying write a function that will fetch the access token and then I will making another function call which will files from a sharepoint folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the first part of this article from [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token#use-postman-to-get-the-azure-ad-token).

Are you sure you set `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the headers?

[image: token with postman]

- For the method, select GET (1)
- For the URI, enter `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/oauth2/token` (2)
- On the `Headers tab` (3) add `Content-Type` key and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the value (4)

[image: body tab]

- Switch to the `Body tab`, and add the following keys and values.

  - Select `form-data`
  - Add `grant_type` key, and type `client_credentials` for the value.
  - Add `client_id` key, and paste the value of `client ID` you noted down earlier.
  - Add `client_secret` key, and paste the value of client secret you noted down earlier.
- Select `Send` to send the request to get the token

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it worked. I used wrong value for the resource header.